# Unable to step-in to Recursive function breakpoint VS2013

Tags: c#, .net, recursion, ienumerable

I was trying to convert an method with for loops to recursion as part of coding Kata practices(trying to solve problems with recursive approach). There's nothing much in the logic but

- The breakpoint is not being hit anywhere in the Recursive method.
- I tried to place a logger(console output) to check if the method was called but nothing was being logged.

Here's the method definition(s):

```
    // Original method with for loop
    public IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int>> GetElementWithLargestDeltaOnTimeline(int[] a)
    {
        int runningLindex = 0;
        int currLValue = a[0];
        int runningHindex = 1;
        int currHvalue = a[1];
        int currDelta = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i < a.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (a[i] < currLValue)
            {
                currLValue = a[i];
                runningLindex = i;
            }

            for (int j = runningLindex + 1; j < a.Length; j++)
            {
                if ((a[j] - currLValue) > currDelta)
                {
                    currDelta = a[j] - currLValue;
                    runningHindex = j;
                    currHvalue = a[j];
                }
            }
        }

        yield return new Tuple<int, int>(currLValue, runningLindex);
        yield return new Tuple<int, int>(currHvalue, runningHindex); 
    }
```

Recursive -

```
    // Trying above method to convert to recursive, 
    // Note - It may not be correct *shy* but the problem is why it's not doing anything(not step through/logging)
    public IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int>> GetElementWithLargestDeltaOnTimelineRec
        (int[] a, int i, int j, int runningLindex, int currLValue, int runningHindex, int currHvalue, int currDelta)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Iteration i-{0}: j-{1} runningLindex-{2} currLValue-{3} runningHindex-{4} currHvalue-{5} currDelta-{6}"
                                   , i, j, runningLindex, currLValue, runningHindex, currHvalue, currDelta);
        if (i < a.Length)
        {
            if (a[i] < currLValue)
            {
                currLValue = a[i];
                runningLindex = i;
            }

            if (j < a.Length)
            {
                if ((a[j] - currLValue) > currDelta)
                {
                    currDelta = a[j] - currLValue;
                    runningHindex = j;
                    currHvalue = a[j];
                }

                GetElementWithLargestDeltaOnTimelineRec(a, i, j++, runningLindex, currLValue, runningHindex, currHvalue, currDelta);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            yield return new Tuple<int, int>(currLValue, runningLindex);
            yield return new Tuple<int, int>(currHvalue, runningHindex);
        }

        GetElementWithLargestDeltaOnTimelineRec(a, i++, runningLindex + 1, runningLindex, currLValue, runningHindex, currHvalue, currDelta);
        yield break;
    }
```

Main -

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var a = new[] { 10, 9, 3, 6, 7, 8, 15, 10, 6 };
        var val = new StockManager();
        var result = val.GetElementWithLargestDeltaOnTimelineRec(a, 0, 0, 0, a[0], 1, a[1], 0);
    }
}
```

**Question(s) -**

- Does recursive method calls are something(incorrect) which is causing
  the issue?
- Why the method is not being called and returning empty
  result without failing/error/warning?

**Additional info -**
.Net 4.5, Visual studio 2013

I also tried running this code on different machine(Just to verify if something is wrong with my VS instance).

Comment: Given the sample code you've posted, your method isn't actually being executed: it returns an `IEnumerable` and you aren't doing anything with it. Try iterating over `result` in `Main()` and you'll see something get logged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a little trick with methods which return `IEnumerable`. You should enumerate them!

Instead of calling `GetElementWithLargestDeltaOnTimelineRec` inside itself you should enumerate it and yield return its elements or store the result to use later. `IEnumerable`s do nothing until they enumerated.

```
foreach (var e in GetElementWithLargestDeltaOnTimelineRec(...))
    yield return e;
```

Or

```
var innerResult = GetElementWithLargestDeltaOnTimelineRec(...);
```

and use `innerResult` somehow that cause it to be enumerated.